# Maximum sum of non consecutive elements (Dynamic Programming)

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

> Given an array of positive integers, what's the most efficient
> algorithm to find non-consecutive elements from this array which, when
> added together, produce the maximum sum?

The dynamic programming solution is to use an auxiliary array `maxSum` holding the max sum up until that particular index. We start by setting the first 2 indices of the array, and fill the rest of the array with `max(array[i]+maxSum[i-2], maxSum[i-1])`.

---

I understand that we cannot add adjacent elements, but I am struggling to understand how the above solution takes into consideration that it is possible for the the previous element in `maxSum[i]` to not be the result of summing with `array[i]`.

For example:

```
index:  0 1 2  3 4

array:  3 5 -7 8 10

maxSum: 3 5 5  _
```

We see that maxSum[2] is not a result of summing with array[2].

To find `maxSum[3] = max(array[3]+maxSum[1], maxSum[2])`, but why don't we consider `maxSum[2] + array[3]`? Since it is possible for maxSum[2] to not consist of the adjacent array[2] value.

Comment: 1. I understand it's an assignment, but why would anyone want this in the real world?
2. In your example, is the max sum 15?
3. One way would be to find the top 3 values and compare their indexes,
A simpler way would be: for(i=0;i<array.length-2;i++) for(j=i+2;j<array.length;j++) track max sum and pair of indexes.

Comment: @iAmOren im practicing an interview question, not an assignment

Comment: same same...  what about my other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how does the above solution take into consideration that it is possible for the previous element in maxSum[i] to not be the result of summing with array[i]?

Simply. If the previous element in maxSum[i] is not to be included in the result of summing with array[i], we can look at maxSum[i - 2]. We do this *explicitly* in

```
array[i]+maxSum[i-2]
```

we compare that against the option of not including array[i], which is

```
maxSum[i-1]
```

Comment: appreciate you taking the time to read/understand my q

Answer (score 0):

First all, you might not understand the procedure completely:

- For each index i, `maxSum` represents the `max` of (sum by including i-th element, sum by excluding i-th element)
- `maxSum[3] = max(array[3]+maxSum[1], maxSum[2])`, because `array[3]+maxSum[1]` represents the sum if `array[3]` is taken, and `maxSum[2]` if `array[3]` is excluded.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you need an explanation of the reasoning, here it is.

Let M[i] be the maximum sum we can obtain by including the **first** i elements of the array A (with the condition that no two are consecutive). There are two possibilities:

1. M[i] includes element i. In this case it cannot include element i-1
   so M[i]=A[i]+M[i-2]
2. M[i] does not include element i. In this case M[i]=M[i-1].

Since we don't know if it actually includes i or not we compute both cases and choose the maximum between the two thus

M[i]=max(M[i-1],A[i]+M[i-2])